# Python - JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes

Tags: python, json

I've checked out the existing answers for this question and I can't find what my specific issue is. I'm trying to parse what I *think* is a valid JSON object, but somehow it's rejecting it.

I used this code to dump the data to the file from an API response:

```
def write_video_ids_to_file(video_ids, video_data_file):
    # Create file if it doesn't exist
    file_is_empty = is_file_empty(video_data_file)
    if file_is_empty:
        open(video_data_file, 'w').close()

    with open(video_data_file, 'a') as file:
        json.dump(video_ids, file, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
        print('collecting video ids')
```

And this code below that's running to try to load that JSON back out of the file seems to be failing:

```
def construct_video_id_array(video_data_file):
    with open(video_data_file, 'r') as file:
        json_data = json.load(file) # <-- Failing here

    video_ids_separate = []
    for video in json_data:
        video_ids_separate.append(video['video_id'])

    return video_ids_separate
```

Here's a sample of my JSON data (there's like 8 MB of it, so I'm not going to post it all):

```
{[
    {
        "channel_id": "UC9CuvdOVfMPvKCiwdGKL3cQ",
        "collection_date": "2020-08-18 20:55:18.854967",
        "publish_date": 1597784402.0,
        "video_id": "5tBnaxQKpHQ"
    },
    {
        "channel_id": "UC9CuvdOVfMPvKCiwdGKL3cQ",
        "collection_date": "2020-08-18 20:55:18.854967",
        "publish_date": 1597698002.0,
        "video_id": "7J3H8ckUaYU"
    }
]}
```

I originally didn't have the **{** at the beginning and end, so I added those. I am not sure if that was the right move, but for what it's worth, it's not working with or without it, just throwing different errors.

Comment: its because you are saying json load file object use: json.load(file.read())

Comment: well no, because I'm not using json.loads() which takes a string. I'm using json.load() which takes a file object.

Comment: oh sorry your write.

Comment: your json is not valid does my post answer your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON content should look like:

```json
{ "your_data":[
    {
        "channel_id": "UC9CuvdOVfMPvKCiwdGKL3cQ",
        "collection_date": "2020-08-18 20:55:18.854967",
        "publish_date": 1597784402.0,
        "video_id": "5tBnaxQKpHQ"
    },
    {
        "channel_id": "UC9CuvdOVfMPvKCiwdGKL3cQ",
        "collection_date": "2020-08-18 20:55:18.854967",
        "publish_date": 1597698002.0,
        "video_id": "7J3H8ckUaYU"
    }
]}
```

This is valid. Check this website out: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/json-load-in-python/ and also https://jsonlint.com/.

All JSON data will need a key, even a list.

Your JSON object should also look like:

```json
{ "your_data":[
    {
        "channel_id": "UC9CuvdOVfMPvKCiwdGKL3cQ",
        "collection_date": "2020-08-18 20:55:18.854967",
        "publish_date": 1597784402.0,
        "video_id": "5tBnaxQKpHQ"
    },
    {
        "channel_id": "UC9CuvdOVfMPvKCiwdGKL3cQ",
        "collection_date": "2020-08-18 20:55:18.854967",
        "publish_date": 1597698002.0,
        "video_id": "7J3H8ckUaYU"
    }
]}
```

So file *json.dump* will dump the proper JSON content in a file.

Comment: How exactly would I give the object a name this way in my code that writes the JSON? I don't want to have to manually go add this field to my file if possible.

Comment: how many files do you have.I don't know sorry maby try regex

Comment: sorry i don't really understand what your asking. is my comment correct.

Comment: well there's two files that I'm doing this with but they hold different data. I was just wondering if it was possible to dump the json data differently with my ```json.dump()``` call. It's dumping it like I posted with out naming the array of objects with a key

Comment: so you have a json object and you want to put it in a file is that correct

Comment: yes, but it's outputting it to the file like I posted, it's not well-formed json. how do I output it correctly with the key "video_data" or something?

Comment: from what i understand you want to load this json data and it is getting a error. Is json load changing anything or is it json.dump. Your json object should be also have a key for the list.

Comment: Well right, that's what I'm asking. How do I add the key using the ```json.dump()``` call. I'm not modifying it at all, ```json.dump()``` is doing the only write to that file at that point, but it's not adding a key.

Comment: what does the file look like does it have the key. If so then json.load must be changing the json object

Comment: no, it didn't have a key before I added it manually

Comment: yes, but I don't want to have to manually add that key if I deploy this on a new machine. I think I figured it out though, I just have to have a few different write calls